# How to trim the spaces between the column headers?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

in which  the coulmn header has spaces how to trim the space and then read the headers...........
my coulns header looks like this

```
loan number     customer name      customer mobile no.......................
```

i tried this statement

```
OleDbCommand odc = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("Select Loan number,Customer name,mobile no,Sanction Date FROM [BAJAJ DUMP$]"), conn);
```

i am geting this error while reading those errors

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Sanction Date'.
```

Comment: can any one help me this plz..............thanks in advance...................

Answer (score 1):

try :
 `Select [Loan number],[Customer name],[mobile no],[Sanction Date] FROM [BAJAJ DUMP$]`

Comment: "Select [Loan Number],[Customer Name],[Date of Birth],[MobileNo.],[Sanction Date] FROM [BAJAJ DUMP$] ....i got this error "'' is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.